# What is the logic behind finding out the primary stress on syllable in the given word?

Tags: grammar, phonology, syllables

For example, the word *co·a·**li**·tion* has its primary stress on the third syllable.

Therefore, on which syllable does the word *el·e·phant* have its primary stress?

Comment: Generally speaking, stress in English can't be predicted from a word's spelling and has to be learned for each word.

Comment: One of the reasons that I loved Spanish; comparably simple stress rules.

Comment: Generally speaking, *pronunciation* in *any language* can't be predicted from a word's spelling and has to be learned for each word. And then re-learned constantly because nothing stops it from changing over time. Or from place to place. Or from person to person. Now *that* is what I call "generally speaking". Leave poor English alone, it's done nothing wrong or fancy. Spelling just does not encode pronunciation. I am not sure where that myth comes from, as anyone can easily dispel it simply by looking at a word. Any word.

Comment: Bloomberg television news (financial, primarily) has a wide variety of English speakers--Australian, British, American--and many non-native English speakers.  Stressed syllables _in the same word_ vary widely.

Comment: This is something that you just have to learn. (And consequently it is sometimes how you can identify a person for whom English is a second language.) Arguably, this is something that the French language has in its favour; its words are pronounced with equal stress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A decent set of rules comes from the [TOEFL website](https://www.toeflgoanywhere.org/learn-these-4-word-stress-rules-improve-your-pronunciation):

(1) Stress the first syllable of:

- Most two-syllable nouns (examples: CLImate, KNOWledge)
- Most two-syllable adjectives (examples: FLIPpant, SPAcious)

(2) Stress the last syllable of:

- Most two-syllable verbs (examples: reQUIRE, deCIDE)

(3) Stress the second-to-last syllable of:

- Words that end in -ic (examples: ecSTATic, geoGRAPHic)
- Words ending in -sion and -tion (examples: exTENsion, retriBUtion)

(4) Stress the third-from-last syllable of:

- Words that end in -cy, -ty, -phy and -gy (examples: deMOCracy,
  unCERtainty, geOGraphy, radiOLogy)
- Words that end in -al (examples:
  exCEPtional, CRItical)

Comment: "HOWEVER in spoken English you'll generally hear people default to emphasizing the first syllable, regardless the word." I'm a native speaker of English, and don't agree with this. It would sound bizarre indeed.

Comment: The distinction between nouns and verbs seems to be good, e.g. "OB-ject" vs "ob-JECT" and "PRE-sent" vs "pre-SENT."

Comment: @anongoodnurse what do you mean, "bizarre indeed"? Certainly you meant to say "BIzarre INdeed"?

Comment: @RegDwigнt - InCRE'ibly eNOUGH', I meant exACT'ly what I said. Your SAR'casm does not adDRESS' my exPRESSED' conCERN'. It is, aGAIN', a red HER'ring, for which you show great FOND'ness.

Comment: :-)  The comments have been delightfully humorous, but I've elected to remove the offending comment since it violated a fundamental tenet of Dr. Seuss: "The writer who breeds more words than he needs, is making a chore for the reader who reads."

Answer (score 5):

Some languages have stresses placed relative to the end of the word, or relative to the beginning.  English stress, to the extent it has a regular system, is placed relative to the end of a word.  Both your examples have (or at least had) stress on the third syllable from the end of the word -- EL-e-phant, co-a-LI-ti-on.  The latter example however has lost a syllable -ti- due to historical sound change, so in contemporary pronunciation, the LI stress winds up on only the second syllable from the end.

*The Sound Pattern of English* by Chomsky and Halle has a thorough-going but disputed analysis of English stress.

Answer (score 0):

The emphasis is on the first syllable--EL-e-phant. I don't know if there is a rule in English that can be applied to all words, since there are so many different sources/languages incorporated into the English language.